# How do I use the codename one migration tool on my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, codenameone

How do I use the [codename](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/android-migration-tool.html) one migration tool on my Android Studio project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are here: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-android-importer

You need to run the tool from command line using the syntax:

```
java -jar AndroidImporter.jar import-project [options]
 -h,--help                         Usage instructions
 -i,--android-resource-dir <arg>   Android project res directory path
 -o,--cn1-project-dir <arg>        Path to the CN1 output project
                                   directory.
 -p,--package <arg>                Java package to place GUI forms in.
 -r,--cn1-resource-file            Path to CN1 output .res file.  Defaults
                                   to theme.res in project dir
```